# Import Json.jar into a simple Java project

Tags: java, json, jar, classpath

I can't possibly figure out how to import Json.jar into a simple Java project(not Maven nor Eclipse). Package structure looks like this:
Project folder
  - data
  - src/com/project/*.java files
  - target/classes/com/project/*.class files

I compile with:
  -javac -d target/classes --source-path src src/com/project/*.java

I run with:
  -java -cp target/classes com.project.Main

As of now, I have tried compiling with -cp *jar path here* and the javac command from above and even when it succeeded I was unable to run it.
Now my question is, where should I put the Json.jar in the package structure and how should I include it in the commands?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The jar must be in the compile classpath **and** in the runtime classpath, otherwise how could the JVM find the classes in the jar file? `javac -cp /path/to/json.jar ...`, `java -cp /path/to/json.jar:target/classes com.project.Main`.

Comment: does it matter though, where is the jar file located? does it have to be in the project folder somewhere?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. But if you don't use a build tool, it's best to put it in some lib folder of your project, so that you can move/zip/commit/clone the whole project and have everything you need.

Comment: okay I am officially dumb, I have even tried it, but always put a space in between the jar path and target/classes... I appreciate your help thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a bad news for you: you'll make a lot of such mistakes later :-) We all do.

Comment: Good to know, can I marked the question as solved somewhere?

Comment: I should have posted the comment as an answer. i'll do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar must be in the compile classpath and in the runtime classpath, otherwise how could the JVM find the classes in the jar file?

```
javac -cp /path/to/json.jar ... 
java -cp /path/to/json.jar:target/classes com.project.Main
```